# Remove all text from string before a character with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

How do I remove the "/" character and the text before it with jQuery? I know how to replace the character, but the text is generated dynamically so unsure how to do that. I guess I need to use regex somehow?

```
<span class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories/Service & Support</a></span>
```

Comment: Do you mind using substring, indexOf from plain javascript?

Comment: Something like `$('.unfoldedlabel a').text(function(_, text) {
        return text.split('/')[1];
      });` might help

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/0d104m3d/

Comment: The first `/` you come across, or the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of the best bits of the answers/comments so far:

```
$('.unfoldedlabel a').text(function(_, text) {
    // return (text.split('/').pop()); // just the original requirement
    return (text.split('/').pop().replace(/\s*/g,'')); // with whitespace removed
});
```

Comment: That worked great. Is it possible to ad a removal of white spaces aswell? ware this wasnt part of the original question, but just realized this would be good to know.

Comment: @Xeptor simply use `@$.trim(text.split('/').pop())`

Comment: @Satpal that doesnt seems to work? not sure if i Wrote it correct though

Comment: I've added a version with the whitespace trimmed. It only removes whitespace at the start and end of the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Lear however Im trying to remove all the whitespace. was thinking of a .replace should work? not sure how to make it repeat though..

Comment: I've updated to include the removal of all whitespace

Answer (score 4):

If you're certain you only have 1 slash:

```
var str = "Accessories/Service & Support";
str = str.split("/").pop();
alert(str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jEQQg/904/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split("/")`;

```
var newString = oldString.split("/");
```

`newString` is then an array of the content of the `oldString` with `newString[0]` the text before / and newString[1] the text after.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/([^\/]+$)/` to negate forward slash character `"/"` , match any characters following forward slash character until end of input string

```js
document.querySelector(".unfoldedlabel")
.textContent = document.querySelector(".unfoldedlabel").textContent
.match(/([^\/]+$)/)[0]
```

```html
<span class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories/Service & Support</a></span>
```